# one block of code prevent another one to work

Tags: javascript

```js
$('.txtags').keyup(function (event) {
 var el = $(this).val().split("\n").pop().toUpperCase();
 el = el.trim();
 $('.poptag').hide();
 $('.poptag').each(function(){
  if ($(this).text().indexOf(el) > -1) {
   $(this).show();
  }
 });
});

$('.poptag').click(function(){
 var a = $(this).text();
 var content = $('.txtags').val();
 var el = content.split("\n").pop();
 el = el.trim();
 content = content.replace(el, '') + a + "\n";
 $('.txtags').val(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='txtags' id='tagsart' rows="5"></textarea>

<div class='poptags' id='poptags'>
<div class='poptag'>2019</div>
<div class='poptag'>ABCPLUS</div>
<div class='poptag'>LOREM</div>
<div class='poptag'>LOREM IPSUM</div>
</div>
```

```
$('.txtags').keyup(function (event) {
    var el = $(this).val().split("\n").pop().toUpperCase();
    el = el.trim();
    $('.poptag').hide();
    $('.poptag').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(el) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

The above works fine.
Now I have the following:

```
$('.poptag').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).text();
    var content = $('.txtags').val();
    var el = content.split("\n").pop();
    el = el.trim();
    content = content.replace(el, '') + a + "\n";
    $('.txtags').val(content);
});
```

This also works, but after clicking on `poptag` - the previous block of code (`txtags keyup`) - deosn't work !

This also works, but after clicking on `poptag` - the previous block of code (`txtags keyup`) - deosn't work !

Comment: Can you provide SO snippet with sample code?

Comment: @Justinas, how can I do that, pls?

Comment: Your Html markup­, However a click event wont trigger a keyup event

Comment: @puerto When editing question there is `<>` on menu bar, or click `ctrl + m`

Comment: @Justinas, I did

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa, I don't want to trigger a `keyup`, but entering again into `.txtags` keyup doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand i just ran your code and they keyup still works after i click

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa, no it doesn't work. after click on `poptag` try to clear `.txtags` an type again.

Comment: IT Does work, Check the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is when you are typing in textbox, you are not introducing new line character "\n". So it works fine as expected

But when you populate textbox by clicking on poptags, you introduce new line character "\n" in the textbox. Now you have to handle this new character also in your logic.

Change your txtags click handler function to below code. It should work.

```
$('.txtags').keyup(function (event) {
var el = $(this).val().split("\n");
var lastEl = el.pop();
if(lastEl=="" && el.length){
    el=el.pop().toUpperCase();
}else{
    el = lastEl.toUpperCase();
}
el = el.trim();
$('.poptag').hide();
$('.poptag').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().indexOf(el) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Logic

```
 $('.txtags').keyup(function (event) {
      var el = $(this).val().split("\n").pop().toUpperCase();
      el = el.trim();
      $('.poptag').hide();
      $('.poptag').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(el) > -1) {
          $(this).show();
        }
      });
    });
```

If the user clicks on say "2019" it will be added to the text area.

Now if the user types something next to it say "2019F" el will be null because your split("\n") returns `["2019F", ""]` then you call pop() on it then it becomes `""` then when you call `indexOf(el)` which return 0, therefore the if statement 0 > -1 will be true so the poptags will be shown again.

I Can't suggest any solutions, since i don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish here, the problem is your logic so it should be simple to change.